# Detecting if special keys such as "Shift were pressed on KeyPress Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function detectspecialkeys(e){
var evtobj=window.event? event : e
if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
alert("you pressed one of the 'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' keys")
}
</script>
```

Here what is difference between window.event and event and e?
Is it required to use this line:

```
var evtobj=window.event? event : e
```

Comment: As you tagged with jQuery, no you don't have to use that line, jQuery normalizes `event.which`

Comment: This is tagged jQuery. jQuery normalizes events across browsers when you use jQuery events. The answer can be different based on context, are you using it or not?